# admininstration section

Tags: php, admin, administration, system-administration

I'm building my first web application(i mean first huge web application)using php but i have some questions about admin section.what are the ways for making admin i mean i thought i could make it this way:
First make an array:

```
$pages = array('post' => 'posts.php', 'category' => 'categories.php');
```

And then read get var check if it's in array:

```
if($pages[$_GET['location']])
    include "$pages[$_GET[location]]";
```

is this a good way?
are there any other ways?
and i was about to forget this one what are admin page html tags and headers?

Answer (score 1):

Always I am creating a own module for admin panel. With own authentification. Admin section in common site isn't a good practice.

Comment: it's not a common site it's a local site in localhost, I'm practicing but i expected more answers and helps.anyway tanks for the answer.